# Send command to new tmux pane?

Tags: tmux

If I want to send a command to a running pane in tmux I can do this:

```
tmux send -t foo ls ENTER
```

I figured I could do something like this to do the same but in a new pane:

```
tmux send ls ENTER
```

Is there an easy way to run in a pane?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152738/how-to-split-a-new-window-and-run-a-command-in-this-new-window-using-tmux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to run a command in a new pane, simply:

```
tmux new-window your command ENTER
```

The issue is that the window is destroyed once the command finishes. Therefore, "tmux new-window ls ENTER" makes no sense. In contrast, "tmux new-window top ENTER" or "tmux new-window watch ls ENTER" seem much more reasonable.

Comment: FWI, if you get to this page wondering how to split the existing window, use the command `tmux split-window your command ENTER`

Comment: `tmux split-window -d your command here` will also return input point to the current pane